# Vue 3 building component as lib

Tags: vue.js, flask, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-composition-api

I have a case of expectation vs reality in my attempt to create a re-usable vue component that can be injected/used in a flask application.

My files:

```
src/components/dataTable.vue (main SFC)
src/components/dataTable.js
src/components/tableBare.vue
src/components/paginationBare.vue
```

dataTable.vue imports the other 3 files

dataTable.vue is built with

`vue-cli-service build --inline-vue --target lib --name data-table src/components/dataTable.vue`

The generated output after build is rendered within a flask/jinja template (about.html, below), but the rendered page is nothing close to the page generated during Vue development.

Where should I start looking?

[image]

[image]

**dataTable.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>

    <CAlert color="info" dismissible>
      <strong>Here</strong> datatables will rise.
    </CAlert>

    
    <div id="edit_form" v-if="editing" class="edit-section col-md-6 ">
        <h2><div v-if="adding">Add user</div><div v-else>Edit user "form.username"</div></h2>
        <form @submit.prevent="onSubmitForm">
          <slot name="editForm"></slot>

          <CButton
              color="primary"
              class="me-1"
              type="submit"
          >Submit</CButton>

          <CButton
              @click.prevent="editing = adding = false"
              color="secondary"
              type="cancel"
          >Cancel</CButton>
        </form>
    </div>


    <div v-if="!editing" class="table-section">
        <h2>[[ capitalize(title) ]]</h2>
            <div v-if="totalRows>0" class="form-row">

                <div class="col-sm-7 my-2">
                    <CButton
                            @click="editing = adding = true"
                            color="primary">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                            <span class="d-none d-md-inline"> Add [[capitalize(title_s)]]</span>
                    </CButton>
                    <small v-if="Object.keys(selected).length===0" class="text-muted ms-2">
                      Click a row to edit or delete.
                    </small>
                    <span v-else>
                        <CButton
                                @click="editing = true"
                                class="ms-1" color="secondary">
                                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                                <span class="d-none d-md-inline"> Edit</span>
                        </CButton>
                        <CButton
                                @click="showMsgBoxConfirm"
                                class="ms-1"
                                color="secondary"><i class="fa fa-trash">
                                </i><span class="d-none d-md-inline"> Delete</span>
                        </CButton>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-5 my-2">
                    <!-- filter box -->
                </div>
            </div>

        <tableBare :items="items"
                   :fields="fields"
                   :sortBy="sortBy"
                   :sortDesc="sortDesc"
                   @changeSortBy="changeSortBy"
                   @rowClick="rowClick"
        ></tableBare>



        <div class="form-row">
          <CInputGroup v-if="totalRows>0">
            <div class="col-md-2 me-1 mb-1">
                <!-- <CFormSelect model-value="perPage" :options="perPageOptions" id="perPageOptions" style="width:120px;"></CFormSelect> -->
                <select v-model="perPage" class="form-select" id="perPageOptions">
                  <option v-for="(opt, idx) in perPageOptions" v-bind:key="idx" :value="opt.value" >
                    [[opt.label]]
                  </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <paginationBare
              class="mb-1"
              :currentPage="currentPage"
              :totalRows="totalRows"
              :perPage="perPage"
              @pageChanged="pageChanged"
            ></paginationBare>
          </CInputGroup>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- <div v-else>No data to display.</div> -->

  </div>
</template>



<script>
import DataTable from '@/components/dataTable.js';
import { useCapitalize } from '@/composables/stringUtils';
import { ref } from 'vue';
import tableBare from './tableBare.vue';
import paginationBare from './paginationBare.vue';
import { CAlert, CInputGroup, CButton, 
        } from '@coreui/bootstrap-vue';


export default {
    components: {
    tableBare, paginationBare,
    CAlert,  CInputGroup, CButton, 
},
    props: ['apiEndpoint'],
    setup(props) {

        const { flashMessage, flashMessageVariant, 
          adding, editing, title, selected, items, fields,
          currentPage, perPage, perPageOptions, totalRows,
          onRowSelected, onFiltered,
          onSortChanged, onSubmitForm, onPageChange,
          unselectRows,
          sortBy, sortDesc, filter } = DataTable();
        console.log(props.apiEndpoint)

        // mutate title
        var title_s
        let title_temp
        title_temp = title.value.split('|')
        title_s = title_temp[0]
        title.value = title_temp.length > 1 ? title_temp[1] : title_temp[0]

        editing.value = false
        
        const mybtableRef = ref(null)

        function showMsgBoxConfirm() {
          // dummy
        }

        function pageChanged(page) {
          currentPage.value = page
          // fetchData('page')
        }

        function rowClick(rowData, idx) {
          unselectRows(idx)
          rowData.selected = !rowData.selected
          selected.value = rowData.selected ? [rowData] : []
        }

        function changeSortBy(sortByVal, sortDescVal) {
          sortBy.value = sortByVal
          sortDesc.value = sortDescVal
        }

        return { 
            flashMessage,
            flashMessageVariant,
            adding,
            editing,
            title, title_s,
            showMsgBoxConfirm,
            selected,
            capitalize:useCapitalize,
            items, fields,
            currentPage, perPage, perPageOptions, totalRows,
            sortBy, sortDesc, filter,
            onRowSelected, onFiltered, onSortChanged,
            onSubmitForm, onPageChange,
            mybtableRef, changeSortBy, rowClick,
            pageChanged,
            }
    }
}

</script>
```

**about.html** (flask/jinja template)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block styles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='data-table/data-table.css') }}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>About Page</h1>
<p>This is the About page.</p>

<div id="app1">
    <data-table :apiEndpoint="'/api_v1/'"></data-table>
</div>

{% endblock %}



{% block scripts %}
    {{ super() }}
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='data-table/data-table.umd.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        const app1 = Vue.createApp({})
        app1.component('data-table', window['data-table']);
        app1.mount('#app1')
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The images indicate that Bootstrap is missing and the table does not load rows. You should be able to inspect both issues in the web console, i.e. check what styles are associated with the classes on your tags, check what resources are loaded in the network tab, check if there are errors in the JS console, etc. Impossible to say what is going on without those details.

Comment: Apparently, every component loads as expected, but are not rendered properly on page. I am using a component set called CoreUI which are not rendering properly, but vanilla BS components render no problem.